# Showing a fragment in a preference activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-preferences

I'm trying to change this [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2) so that it's using PreferenceActivity instead of FragmentActivity.

The sample has an activity:

```
public abstract class BaseGamePlayActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BillingProvider {
```

that loads a fragment in a handler (using the FragmentActivity):

```
/**
 * User clicked the "Buy Gas" button - show a purchase dialog with all available SKUs
 */
public void onPurchaseButtonClicked(final View arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Purchase button clicked.");

    if (mAcquireFragment == null) {
        mAcquireFragment = new AcquireFragment();
    }

    if (!isAcquireFragmentShown()) {
        mAcquireFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);

        if (mBillingManager != null
                && mBillingManager.getBillingClientResponseCode()
                        > BILLING_MANAGER_NOT_INITIALIZED) {
            mAcquireFragment.onManagerReady(this);
        }
    }
}
```

My code uses, PreferenceActivity, instead (from which I need the preference listeners):

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements BillingProvider {
```

and the handler:

```
/**
 * Handle an iap 
 */
public void onPurchaseIapButtonClicked(final Preference preference) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Iap purchase button clicked.");

    if (mAcquireFragment == null) {
        mAcquireFragment = new AcquireFragment();
    }

    if (!isAcquireFragmentShown()) {
        // --------------------------
        // There is no getSupportFragmentManager in PreferenceActivity  
        // --------------------------
        mAcquireFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TAG);

        if (mBillingManager != null
                && mBillingManager.getBillingClientResponseCode()
                > BILLING_MANAGER_NOT_INITIALIZED) {
            mAcquireFragment.onManagerReady(this);
        }
    }
}
```

How can a fragment be loaded by a (class extending) PreferenceActivity?

The project is structured into two parts:

- game logic in unity (which is exported as an .aar)
- android logic (handles interfacing with .aar through a shared preference)

On the android side it looks like:

```
/**
 * Reference to default {@code SharedPreferences}.
 */
private SharedPreferences mDefaultPreferences;

/**
 * Notifies C# side about preferences changes.
 */
private final SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener =
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        LiveWallpaperUnityFacade.getEventsProxy().preferenceChanged(key);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Notify C# about opening
    LiveWallpaperUnityFacade.getEventsProxy().preferencesActivityTriggered();

    // Get Preferences and attach preferences change listener
    mDefaultPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    mDefaultPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Detach preferences change listener
    mDefaultPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener);

    // Close the Activity. This is required because preferences could be changed from Unity,
    // but values in Activity won't be refreshed. By closing the Activity each time when it goes
    // into background, we can be sure it'll always have up-to-date values.
    finish();
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `PreferenceActivity` at all. See the [Preferences guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) for how you should be writing preferences.

Comment: The project uses an .aar export from unity, that is being updated through a shared preference (from android) (updated question).